# will_paginate appears wrong in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

**UPDATE:** I found through chrome dev tools that the custom.css.scss below wasn't being used in production. Does anyone know why heroku wouldn't use some scss?

I'm following ruby on rails tutorial and the pagination for the index appears off in production. It appears as if the image is not clearing the above image. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

This is how the index looks in development:

[image: How index looks in development]

This is how the index looks in production:
[image: How index looks in production]

Here is the css in custom.css.scss:

```
/* Masters index */

.masters {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  li {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    &:last-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    }
  }
 }
```

The index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'All masters') %>
<h1>All masters</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="masters">
    <%= render @masters %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

_master.html.erb

```
<li>
    <%= gravatar_for master, size: 52 %>
    <%= link_to master.name, master %>
    <% if current_master.admin? && !current_master?(master) %>
        | <%= link_to "delete", master, method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this master?" } %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking out your trusty web debugger (Firebug or the tools in Chrome or Safari) and comparing the CSS and Markup in prod to the CSS and Markup in dev.

Comment: I found through chrome dev tools that the custom.css.scss below wasn't being used in production. Would you happen to know why heroku wouldn't use the scss?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I had to do rake assets:precompile in order to fix it.

Comment: I also got the same css problem in development, how did you fix that? thx